# LiteDB FileStreamFactory.GetStream (System.Boolean canWrite, System.Boolean sequencial) System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation on path /data/user/0/

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, litedb

I'm having this issue on Litedb with Android app (built with xamarin forms),

Version: 5.0.11

Note:

- I ensure that there is only one instance of the LiteDatabase in my app, by registering it as a singleton in my service provider at startup.
- I Dispose my LiteDatabase object only when the application's MainActivity fires the "OnDestroyed" method.
  When testing on my local devices, I have no issues. But in prod, I find several android devices having the issue below. Please help, Is there something I'm doing wrong?

> FileStreamFactory.GetStream (System.Boolean canWrite, System.Boolean sequencial)
> System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation on path /data/user/0/

Here is how I create the single instance of my LiteDatabase:

```
        var baseDir = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;
        var dbPath = Path.Combine(baseDir, options.Value.DatabaseFileName);
        var dbDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(dbPath);
        if (!Directory.Exists(dbDir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(dbPath));
        }
        Connection = new ConnectionString
        {
            Filename = dbPath,
            Connection = ConnectionType.Direct
        };
        Database = new LiteDatabase(Connection);
```

Here is the code I call to dispose the database. (Note: I only call it when the Main Activity's Destroy method is called)

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Database?.Commit();
        Database?.Dispose();
    }
```

Here is the error stack trace.

> System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode
> mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share,
> System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous,
> System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001b7] in
> <9a2141e59f004b13b49be68b4ea0bbf4>:0 System.IO.FileStream..ctor
> (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess
> access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize,
> System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00000] in
> <9a2141e59f004b13b49be68b4ea0bbf4>:0 (wrapper
> remoting-invoke-with-check)
> System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,System.IO.FileOptions)
> FileStreamFactory.GetStream (System.Boolean canWrite, System.Boolean
> sequencial) <.ctor>b__0 () Lazy`1[T].ViaFactory (System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) Lazy`1[T].ExecutionAndPublication (System.LazyHelper
> executionAndPublication, System.Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
> Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () Lazy`1[T].get_Value () StreamPool.get_Writer
> () LiteDB.Engine.DiskService..ctor (LiteDB.Engine.EngineSettings
> settings, System.Int32[] memorySegmentSizes) [0x000ab] in
> <7dd2c2ae6ae04572a54f6c996328226c>:0 LiteDB.Engine.LiteEngine..ctor
> (LiteDB.Engine.EngineSettings settings) [0x00173] in
> <7dd2c2ae6ae04572a54f6c996328226c>:0 ConnectionString.CreateEngine ()
> LiteDB.LiteDatabase..ctor (LiteDB.ConnectionString connectionString,
> LiteDB.BsonMapper mapper) [0x00034] in
> <7dd2c2ae6ae04572a54f6c996328226c>:0
> MyAppe.MobileApp.CacheServices.LiteDb.Shared.LiteDBConnection..ctor
> (Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[TOptions] options) [0x00055] in <a0bb4854b1d6427388c3f8741e779843>:0 (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&) RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) RuntimeConstructorInfo.DoInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext context) CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSiteMain
> (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument) CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache
> (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
> callSite,
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext
> context) CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext context) CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSiteMain
> (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)
> CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache
> (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
> transientCallSite,
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext
> context) CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext context) CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSiteMain
> (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument) CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache
> (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
> callSite,
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext
> context) CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite callSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor (System.Type serviceType) ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (TKey key,
> System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory) ServiceProvider.GetService (System.Type serviceType, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) ServiceProvider.GetService (System.Type serviceType) ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService (System.IServiceProvider provider, System.Type serviceType) ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T] (System.IServiceProvider provider) MyAppe.MobileApp.App..ctor (System.Action`1[T] configuration, System.Action`2[T1,T2]
> dependencyServiceConfiguration) [0x00057] in
> <4c7de3aa76d348f2b3428d0d66c81620>:0 MainActivity.OnCreate
> (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
> AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__7_0 (System.Object state)
> SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0 ()
> Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () IRunnableInvoker.n_Run
> (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) (wrapper
> dynamic-method)
> Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.132(intptr,intptr)

. Can someone please help? is there a trick somewhere?

Comment: That error message is useless without a stack-trace; eg. https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/1709 ...on Android, `ContentProvider` prevent this. What if I launch your app twice in multi-window mode?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I just added a stacktrace.

Comment: Do you know which line came up with the error?

Comment: I'm encountering this issue too, and it seems to occur when resuming our Xamarin.Android app (for example, after toggling the dark/light theme) when registering the ILiteDb to an instance similar to the OP.

Comment: @DamienDoumer, along with the code for creating, can you share your code for how you're disposing the LiteDatabase as well?

Comment: Hello, @Reisclef I updated the post with the code.

Comment: Do you know which phones have this problem? What is the corresponding Android version?